# Error on validate Json: No implicit format for Map

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am new in Scala+Play. I am trying to import a code from the other project that creates an object o mongodb but before it, the code use Json validator with implicits. My object is formed of two types: Valunit and CreateDatumRequest. The error is on the line "implicit val createDatumRequestFmt = Json.format[CreateDatumRequest]" but says about the Valunit object on the above line.

```
No implicit format for Map[String,Option[nl.amc.ebioscience.rosemary.models.core.Valunit]] available.
```

.

```
@Singleton
class DataController @Inject() (securityService: SecurityService) extends Controller with JsonHelpers {
.....
  case class CreateDatumRequest(
      name: String,
      parent: Option[Datum.Id],
      remarks: Option[String],
      category: Tag.Id, // Datum Category tag
      dict: Map[String, Option[Valunit]]) {

    def validate(workspaceId: Tag.Id): Either[String, Map[DefaultModelBase.Id, BaseEntity]] = {
........
}
  object CreateDatumRequest {
    implicit val valunitFmt = Json.format[Valunit]
    implicit val createDatumRequestFmt = Json.format[CreateDatumRequest]
  }
......
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining Reads for `dict: Map[String, Option[Valunit]])`.You can read more here.https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#complex-reads

Comment: why cant I use "Json.format", that is easier? If I take out the line "implicit val createDatumRequestFmt = Json.format[CreateDatumRequest]" my code compiles fine. I think there is something wrong on my case class CreateDatumRequest

Comment: the problem is something related to "dict: Map[String, Option[Valunit]]" into the CreateDatumRequest.

Comment: AFAIK play-json needs the Reads/Writes for custom object (in your case it is ` Valunit ` ). You can try with json4s if you want to avoid this.